# android fragment not work when callback onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, onactivityresult

I got activity A which contain a fragment list and a activity B which is a search filter page.

I go to from activity A to B. Then I specific some query, then my code called

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)
```

and go back Activity A's `onActivityResult()` this method call fragment's search method and make a request then populate the result to the fragment list.

Everything is ok. However, when i change the screen orientation, my code not longer work due the list fragment in Activity A is recreated and look like once it is recreate, the code cannot deal the new list fragment instance and throw an exception.

however i found that if the list fragment is specific in `layout.xml` file of activity A. (with  tag) I don't have this issue above.

any idea ?

Comment: how do you call your fragment, from activity programmatically or you have it in xml?

Comment: What is the exception? Please post the stack trace

Comment: that is 2 way, If I specific the fragment in layout.xml i don't have any issue and it work fine.

However, when i create my fragment programatically

myFragment = new MyFragment();//this var is in Activity A instance variable
fragmentManager.replace(R.id.content, myfragment).commit();

first time run ok, then i change the screen orientation, go to Acitvity B to call search (it will return to Activity A), then Exception occurs 

the exception show java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo.

Comment: after some debug, I just found out that when call myfragment = new MyFragment(); before it finish instantiate, I had ccall myfragment.doSomething() which causing nullpointerException due to some variable not yet created. I will use the declaration approach instead. thx !